# minted environment in frame causes error

Tags: beamer, minted

There is [an overleaf template for pythonTEX](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/using-pythontex-on-overleaf/qfjttkyfdtyt#.Wknzud-WaUk). I change it's document class into **beamer** and then I find a strange error with the following code:

```
\begin{frame}{Example}
\begin{minted}{latex}
\py{2+2}
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
```

error information:

```
Runaway argument?
 \py {2+2} \end {minted} 
Paragraph ended before \FV@BeginScanning was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.44 \end{frame}
```

A simple change can make it work well:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{minted}{latex}
\py{2+2}
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
```

Why can't I set the frame title directly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need a fragile frame for all verbatim environments and minted is one of them.

Comment: @TeXnician, so it's an usual situation?

Comment: Yes. It is far from being strange, but it is by design. A fragile frame is needed as there is special handling concerning the content (which is not needed for normal frames). `minted` is one of the verbatim environments (=basically any code environment) which requires this special treatment.

Comment: @Bettertomo You can still set the framtitle directly, you just have to combine it with the fragile option, e.g. `\begin{frame}[fragile]{title}
test
\end{frame}`

Comment: @TeXnician would you like to write an answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`minted` is one of the many verbatim environments you will find when using source code in LaTeX. Those verbatim environments need special treatment (the `fragile` option) by design which is usually not needed for "simple things", e.g. itemize etc.

Hence it is also by design that you need to tell LaTeX to handle your frame specially by using the option. You do not need to set the frametitle using another command, `\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}` will suffice.