# iftoggle with minted

Tags: minted, etoolbox

I have a problem with the minted package in combination with `etoolbox`'s `iftoggle`. It should be related (or basically be the same error) to this `beamer` question: [minted environment in frame causes error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408337/minted-environment-in-frame-causes-error) but the there stated solution (using a `fragile` frame) cannot be applied in this way to a standard document.

The following MWE gives an error when `\toggletrue{test}`:

```
\documentclass{report}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{test}
\toggletrue{test}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\iftoggle{test}{
    \begin{minted}
    test
    \end{minted}
}{}
test
\end{document}
```

The error is

```
(./mwe.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \def
l.15 }
      {}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `\iftoggle{<toggle>}{<true>}{<false>}` expects a `<toggle>`, yet you supply it with something else. That's the problem. What is it that you're really after?

Comment: This will not work because the `\iftoggle` grabs the verbatim environment as argument, which will make it not work.

Comment: @Werner: sorry that was a typo in the mwe, I fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a `minted` environment in the argument to another command.

For this special case, you can do

```
\iftoggle{test}{\iftrue}{\iffalse}
\begin{minted}
test
\end{minted}
\fi
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{test}
\toggletrue{test}

\begin{document}
\iftoggle{test}{\iftrue}{\iffalse}
\begin{minted}{text}
test
\end{minted}
\fi

test

\togglefalse{test}
\iftoggle{test}{\iftrue}{\iffalse}
\begin{minted}{text}
test
\end{minted}
\fi

test

\end{document}
```

[image]